# imagemagick trim but keep canvas size and *position*

Tags: imagemagick

Friends,

I need to `-trim` some images but keep the original canvas size. Works like this:

`convert in.png -fuzz 10% -trim -background white -set page "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" +repage out.png`

But how can I position the trimmed image part at it's *original position*? `-gravitiy center` is not an option as the to-be-trimmed part usually not at the canvas center.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `-trim` an image, then use `-flatten` to lay it back onto its original canvas. Try this command...

```
convert logo: -background none -trim -flatten trimmed.png
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thanks very much! Never stumbled upon -flatten. You never stop learning news things with imagemagick....

Answer (score 2):

@GeeMack's answer is certainly simpler and more succinct, but if you need more flexibility for dinking around, another way is to get the image height and width and the trimbox in one invocation and use them in the next - maybe with adaptation.

So, starting with this image:

[image]

```
# Get image width and height and the trim-box
read geom trim < <(magick start.png -format "%G %@"  info:)

# Make a new white canvas same size as original and trim new image onto it
magick -size $geom xc:white \( start.png -crop $trim \) -flatten  result.png
```

[image]

I put an artificial yellow border around it so you can see the extent of it on SO's white background.

Comment: Mark, that's an interesting approach I will certainly be able to use an upcoming project. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, you're welcome. Please don't forget to accept ✅ @GeeMack's excellent answer. Come back and ask a new question if you get stuck again - questions, and answers, are free.